# Does anyone know how to implement a search bar with tabs like that similar to instagram using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-appbar

I want to know how to build a search bar where it filters the users search input into groups or tabs such as people, tags, places just like what instagram has but I don't know how to do this!

Answer (score 2):

It could look like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
//          home: Scaffold(
//        body: Container(child: SearchButton()),
          home: Body()),
    );

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            cursorColor: Colors.white,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.people)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.location_city)),
          ]),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [Container(), Container()]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wanted result:[image]

Result from Code: [image]

Comment: I want a search bar that has tabbars at the bottom of the search bar

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or a concept

Comment: Your code has a bit of an error with the tab bar it's say no tabcontroller

Comment: Please don't write entire code solutions for people who are too lazy to make any effort for themselves.

Comment: Ok, I won't do it again.

Answer (score -1):

use UniqueKey() for that

example
Scaffold(
backgroundColor: ColorConstant.colorWhite,
body: Container(
height: size.height,
child: Column(
children: [
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: ColorConstant.colorWhite,
//border: Border.all(),
),
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
child: Column(
children: [
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
top: 50.0, left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15),
child: Stack(
clipBehavior: Clip.none,
children: [
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
Container(
width: 265,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG
.withOpacity(0.1),
),
child: TextFormField(
controller: _searchController,
onChanged: (text) {
if (text != null) {
setState(() {
//  callFriendSuggestionListApi(0, text, true);
//  print("inside");
//  DiscoveryPostTabScreen(text);
searchText = text;
// _Controller.animateTo(2);
});
}
},
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 16,
color: ColorConstant.textColor2,
fontFamily: 'HK Medium'),
decoration: new InputDecoration(
hintText: "Search Friend",
isDense: true,
// Added this
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
hintStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize: 16,
color: ColorConstant.hintColor,
fontFamily: 'HK Medium'),
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG
.withOpacity(0.1),
width: 0.1),
),
enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
borderSide: BorderSide(
color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG
.withOpacity(0.1),
width: 0.1),
),
prefixIcon: Icon(
Icons.search,
// color: ColorConstant.errorIconColor,
size: 27,
),
suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
print("object");
},
child: Icon(
Icons.close,
color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG,
size: 25,
),
),
),
),
),
Text("cancel",
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: "HK Bold",
fontSize: 16,
color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG)),
],
),
],
),
),
SizedBox(
height: 10,
),
Container(
height: 30,

```
                    // height: 50,
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _Controller,

                      // controller: _controller,
                      unselectedLabelColor: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG,
                      tabs: [
                        Container(
                          child: Tab(
                            child: Text("Posts",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "HK Medium", fontSize: 16)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Tab(
                            child: Text("Friends",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "HK Medium", fontSize: 16)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Tab(
                            child: Text("Places",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "HK Medium", fontSize: 16)),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Tab(
                            child: Text("Tags",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "HK Medium", fontSize: 16)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],

                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                      labelColor: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG,
                      // indicatorWeight: 5,
                      indicatorColor: ColorConstant.colorBlack,

                      // indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                      indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: ColorConstant.colorIntroBG, width: 2),

                        // insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60.0, 0.0, 60.0, 40.0),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: ColorConstant.borderColorOTP,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
          controller: _Controller,
          key: UniqueKey(),
          children: [
            DiscoveryPostTabScreen(_searchController.text),
            DiscoveryFriendsScreen(_searchController.text),
            DiscoveryPlacesScreen(_searchController.text),
            DiscoveryTagsScreen(_searchController.text),
          ],
        )),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).